# Fetching the registeroutparameter of mysql procedure in java

Tags: java, mysql

I have a procedure in **mysql** with the signature

```
"coursePK bigint(20), groupName varchar(1000), userPK bigint(20), newClassPK bigint(20), assignmentFlag varchar(1), rosterFlag varchar(1), gradebookFlag varchar(1), isHavingMasterClass varchar(1), OUT newBookPK bigint(20)"
```

The procedure has `Start transaction` and `Commit` statements at the end.
And after commit I am setting the value of the OUT Parameter.

Now, my java code is using Callable statement for calling the procedure and when I am fetching the out parameter using `callableStatement.getString(index)` or `callableStatement.getInt(index)`, I am always getting null and 0 respectively.

But When I am executing the procedure from mysql query browser and adding the line `SELECT newBookPK` at end, I am getting the correct output parameter.

So please help me in getting the correct value from Java code too.

Where I am wrong in fetching the output parameter from JAVA.

Here is the java Code :

```
callableStatement = conn.prepareCall("{call copy_custombook_details(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}"); //coursePK bigint(20), groupName varchar(1000), userPK bigint(20), newClassPK bigint(20), assignmentFlag varchar(1), rosterFlag varchar(1), gradebookFlag varchar(1), isHavingMasterClass varchar(1), OUT newBookPK bigint(20)
count=1;
callableStatement.setString(count++, coursePK);
callableStatement.setString(count++, groupName);
callableStatement.setString(count++, userPK);
callableStatement.setString(count++, newClassPK);
callableStatement.setString(count++, "N");
callableStatement.setString(count++, "N");
callableStatement.setString(count++, "N");
callableStatement.setString(count++, isHavingMasterClass);
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(count++, Types.VARCHAR);
callableStatement.execute();
newBookPK = callableStatement.getString(9);
```

Comment: Show us the code where you *register* the out parameter

Comment: You added `callableStatement.execute();` to your code. What is it's effect? If succeeded, accept an answer.

Comment: No change. Actually, my code has the `callableStatement.execute()` from the very beginning, but is of no use.

Answer (score 0):

*`When I am executing the procedure from mysql query browser ...`*
And, in your java code, where are you calling to execute the statement?

In-between

```
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(count++, Types.VARCHAR);
newBookPK = callableStatement.getString(9);
```

include

```
callableStatement.execute();
```

And then `getString( 9 )` should be returning something desired.

Answer (score 0):

The route cause for the issue is in mysql procedure signature. If there is OUT parameters in the procedure, those **should be define before IN parameters**.

In your case, procedure signature need to change as

`OUT newBookPK bigint(20), coursePK bigint(20), groupName varchar(1000), userPK bigint(20), newClassPK bigint(20), assignmentFlag varchar(1), rosterFlag varchar(1), gradebookFlag varchar(1), isHavingMasterClass varchar(1)`

and java code need to change according to that order.